# SFTP connection successful, but can't upload files

Tags: server, openssh, sftp, filezilla

I followed this [guide](http://devtidbits.com/2011/06/29/implement-a-sftp-service-for-ubuntudebian-with-a-chrooted-isolated-file-directory/).

I am using Ubuntu Server and Filezilla, and I can succesfully connect. However, I can only read and download files, not upload or edit them. If I change the file permissions to either 777 or 766, Filezilla can no longer connect.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your chroot path must be owned by root and have permissions of 755 or 750. If you change that sshd will reject connections, because such a chrooted environment is considered insecure. Writing to the chrooted directory with sftp is not possible.

You should make a new subdirectory under the chroot directory, and that directory's ownership and permissions can be changed to anything. So you can write to that subdirectory.